# Are employees in the EU more protected than in the US for sexual harassment?

Tags: netherlands

For example, I know someone who was hired in the US for companyX. CompanyX has three locations, one in the Netherlands, one in the US, and one in Australia. CompanyX told my friend that he must work in the Netherlands for 4 years and afterwards will be working in the US branch. To my knowledge, my friend is working on a visa. If my friend sexually harasses someone on the job, is he tried based on US law or EU law? And if it's EU then is he more protected than in the US?

Comment: There is a one question per post rule, and you have two here. Try and find the answer to your first question elsewhere (either elsewhere on this Stack or elsewhere on the 'net) or resubmit as two separate questions. On the second question, try to make it so the answer is less likely to be opinion-based. I know it's not entirely opinion-based as is, but something along the lines of the following would work better: "Are there harsher punishments for sexual harassment in the EU vs. the US?" or "Are there more instances of legal actions brought by EU or US workers re: sexual harasSomethin

Answer (score 1):

If your friend is in the Netherlands, and goes to court for something he did in the Netherlands, then quite obviously he will be tried under Dutch law.

I'm not aware of any particular protections for anyone who sexually harasses others on the job, neither in the USA nor in the Netherlands. Is that actually the question you wanted to ask?